# ReactNative <Text> is shifting when changing content because of different alphabets, see gif

Tags: react-native

I am changing alphabets in a Text element but I get this slight shifting of elements. I have tried adding padding, margin and wrapping with other empty s but I keep getting this shifting as shown in the video. I've also used the various props options (need to only use the cross platform ones) but to no avail.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWm1q.jpg

And my text is:

```
<Text style={{
  fontSize: 24,
  textAlign: 'center',
  paddingTop: 5,
  paddingBottom: 5}}>
```

Comment: Do you have a container for Text Component?

Comment: @AjithPandian yes, tried with & without container

Comment: Did you tried setting fixed height in Text or Container Component?

Comment: @AjithPandian giving text a fixed height worked, thanks! :)

Comment: Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit2**: Correct answer (credits to [Ajith Pandian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6134070/ajith-pandian)) is that the height should have fixed value.

---

I think it's expected behaviour. If the app is iOS only you can try hard coding height and using `adjustsFontSizeToFit` to force the font to scale down.

Edit: This answer is posted with regards to RN 0.45.0 and older.

Comment: 1) Why is it expected behavior? 2) No, I need cross-platform solution =/

Comment: With adjustsFontSizeToFit I get even stranger behavior, the text keeps getting smaller and smaller and in the limit goes to 0

Comment: I think it's an expected behaviour because Text component measures its bounds according to the content. It cannot take into account all glyphs from a font because there would be a strange gap for most usual applications.

Comment: Makes sense, so fixed height seems to be correct way to go about it